# HTML Picklist does not show on webpage, but does appear in HTML editor

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, content-management-system, picklist

I've been struggling with creating a form on my webpage. I can't find the problem with a dropdown picklist i've created in HTML. When I enter the code below in a online HTML editor it works fine. When I enter it in our CMS to post it on the webpage it works as well. But when I actually open the webpage the dropdownmenu does not show. All I'm left with is the title "Web Color". Can someone review the code below and help me out?

```
<p><select id="00HHH0000YYXXXX" title="Web Color" name="00HHH0000YYXXXX">
<option value="">-- None --</option>
<option value="Blue">BLUE</option>
<option value="Red">RED</option>
<option value="Green">GREEN</option>
<option value="Yellow">YELLOW</option>
<option value="Buzz Lightyear">BUZZ LIGHTYEAR</option>
</select></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should accept one of the answers, or add more details if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ending paragraph tag at the end
`</p>`
which does not have a paragraph opening tag. I don't know if this is the solution but that's what I notice

Comment: You're right, I've made a mistake copying the code from the texteditor to here.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the html you provided, could you share the whole form? It sounds like there is a html tag opened somewhere and never closed or something. Or quotes being opened and not closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly likely to be caused by some invalid HTML elsewhere in your webpage.

Use the **[HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)** to determine exactly where the error is.

Below is your dropdown, and as you can see, it is rendering okay.

```html
<select id="00HHH0000YYXXXX" title="Web Color" name="00HHH0000YYXXXX">
  <option value="">-- None --</option>
  <option value="Blue">BLUE</option>
  <option value="Red">RED</option>
  <option value="Green">GREEN</option>
  <option value="Yellow">YELLOW</option>
  <option value="Buzz Lightyear">BUZZ LIGHTYEAR</option>
</select>
```

(also, you shouldn't need/ want to be surrounding the dropdown with `<p>`)